# How to use a bash command in awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Here is my problem

I have a File 1 where I have some data

```
Var1.1   Var1.2   Var1.3
Var2.1   Var2.2   Var2.3
Var3.1   Var3.2   Var3.3
```

And I have a File 2 that I would like edit thanks to the above data

File2 (1)

```
***pattern with Var2.1***
some text...
```

File2(2)

```
***pattern with Var2.1***
Here I want to add Var2.2 and Var2.3
some text
```

My first solution is to use AWK, but I don't know to include a bash command in. The AWK should make something like:

- Search the pattern in the File2
- When awk get it, awk calls a script which returns the wanted values from the File1.
- Then awk can edit the File2

don't hesitate to explain me other possibilities if there are which are more simple !

Thank you !

Comment: It's not clear what you want, you need to provide explicit examples of input and expected output.

Comment: What do you need more than I already gave ?

Comment: I don't think "imbricate" means what you think it means. I would use "include" or "incorporate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to run an external script to accomplish what you want. It can be done completely within a short AWK script.

```
awk 'FNR == NR {arr[$1] = $2 " " $3; next} {print; for (lookup in arr) {if ($0 ~ lookup) {split(arr[lookup], a); print "Here I want to add " a[1] " and " a[2]}}}' File1 File2
```

Explanation:

- `FNR == NR {arr[$1] = $2 " " $3; next}` - Loop through the first file and save all the values in an array indexed by the first column. The record number equals the file record number for the first file.
- `print` - Print every input line.
- `for (lookup in arr) {if ($0 ~ lookup) {` - Loop through each of the array indices and see if the input line matches.
- `split(arr[lookup], a)` - Split the value stored at the matched index into a temporary array.
- `print "Here I want to add " a[1] " and " a[2]` - Print some text using the two values resulting from the split.

Comment: I try this method and I tell you, but it's seems to be what I am searching for ! Thank you !

Comment: Please, answer the question : "How to use a bash command inside awk"

Comment: @NoémienKocher: AWK has the `system()` function so you could do, as an example, `awk 'BEGIN {system("echo $BASH_VERSION")}`. You can also send a command to Bash through a pipe: `awk 'BEGIN { print "echo $BASH_VERSION" | "/bin/bash"; close("/bin/bash") }'`. You can also use `getline` to capture the output of the command: `awk 'BEGIN { cmd = "echo $BASH_VERSION"; while ( (cmd | getline result) > 0 ) { print result }; close(cmd)}'`.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I run an external command from within awk to base64-decode a string:

```
cmd = "/usr/bin/base64 -i -d <<< " $2 " 2>/dev/null"
while ( ( cmd | getline result ) > 0 ) { }
close(cmd)
split(result, a, "[:=,]")
name=a[2]
```

Perhaps you can get some inspiration from it...